# animate width. Why it doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to expand width of each `a` when I hover over it. With the current jquery script, both `a` expand. I've tried different combinations, I can get my head around it. Help! Thanks :) PS: For some reason the jQuery script, which expands both `a` in my website, doesn't expand anything here in SO.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".rightSocial").children().hover(function() {
      $(this).css("width", "100px");
    },
    function() {
      $(this).css("width", "50px");
    });
});
```

```css
.rightSocial {
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 20px;
}
.rightSocial a {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  right: 0px;
}
.rightTwitter {
  background: red;
}
.rightFB {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rightSocial">
  <p>Share</p>
  <a href="#" class="rightTwitter">Twitter</a>
  <a href="#" class="rightFB">FB</a>
</div>
```

Comment: *For some reason the jQuery script, which expands both `a` in my website, doesn't expand anything here in SO.* Because you didn't include jQuery source in your SO snippet :) Just added a CDN source to display the output.

Comment: looks like solved already :)

Comment: @SachinKanungo it expands to the right, that is why...!!! :) Thanks for your edit, Manoj, my code was not working because I forgot the jquery library link on top. Ok, time for me work further on this one :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example for you using pretty much the logic that you are using.

**This will do the trick**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.rightSocial').children().on('mouseenter',function(){
       $(this).css('width','100px');
       });

    $('.rightSocial').children().on('mouseleave',function(){
       $(this).css('width','50px');
       });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c8ttutrz/

**This will do the trick, but with a smooth animation**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.rightSocial').children().on('mouseenter',function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({
            width : '100px'
            });
        });

 $('.rightSocial').children().on('mouseleave',function(){
      $(this).stop().animate({
          width : '50px'
          });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c8ttutrz/1/

**I would go for this one though. Instead of .children(), add a secondary class**

You could just also add another class to your elements. Let's call it "adjustWidth".

```
<a href="#" class="rightTwitter adjustWidth">Twitter</a>
```

And then do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.adjustWidth').on('mouseenter',function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({
            width : '100px'
            });
        });
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to expand only the anchor tags, use `.rightSocial a` instead of `children()` which currently works on all child items including the `p` tag which is not expected as per your question.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".rightSocial a").hover(function() {
      $(this).css("width", "100px");
    },
    function() {
      $(this).css("width", "50px");
    });
});
```

```css
.rightSocial {
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 20px;
}
.rightSocial a {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  right: 0px;
}
.rightTwitter {
  background: red;
}
.rightFB {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rightSocial">
  <p>Share</p>
  <a href="#" class="rightTwitter">Twitter</a>
  <a href="#" class="rightFB">FB</a>
</div>
```